# Stick (line segments) percolation algorithm - graph theory?

Tags: algorithm, ram

I wrote an algorithm for study stick percolation (i.e.: networks between line segments that intersect between them). In my algorithm N sticks (line segments) are created inside a rectanglar box of sides 'b' and 'h' and then, one by one, the algorithm explores the intersection between all line segments. This is a Monte Carlo simulation, so the 'experiment' is executed many times (no less than 100 times). Writen like that, very much RAM is consumed:

```
array_x1=uniform.rvs(loc=-b/2, scale=b, size=N)  
array_y1=uniform.rvs(loc=-h/2, scale=h, size=N)
array_x2=uniform.rvs(loc=-b/2, scale=b, size=N)  
array_y2=uniform.rvs(loc=-h/2, scale=h, size=N)  

M = np.zeros([N,N])  

for u in xrange(100):  ----> This '100' is the number of experiments.
    for j in xrange(N):
       if j>0:
         x_A1B1 = array_x2[j]-array_x1[j]
        y_A1B1 = array_y2[j]-array_y1[j]
        x_A1A2 = array_x1[0:j]-array_x1[j]
        y_A1A2 = array_y1[0:j]-array_y1[j]      
        x_A2A1 = -1*x_A1A2
        y_A2A1 = -1*y_A1A2
        x_A2B2 = array_x2[0:j]-array_x1[0:j]
        y_A2B2 = array_y2[0:j]-array_y1[0:j]
        x_A1B2 = array_x2[0:j]-array_x1[j]
        y_A1B2 = array_y2[0:j]-array_y1[j]
        x_A2B1 = array_x2[j]-array_x1[0:j]
        y_A2B1 = array_y2[j]-array_y1[0:j]

        p1 = x_A1B1*y_A1A2 - y_A1B1*x_A1A2
        p2 = x_A1B1*y_A1B2 - y_A1B1*x_A1B2
        p3 = x_A2B2*y_A2B1 - y_A2B2*x_A2B1
        p4 = x_A2B2*y_A2A1 - y_A2B2*x_A2A1

        condition_1=p1*p2
        condition_2=p3*p4                         

        for k in xrange (j):
            if condicion_1[k]<=0 and condicion_2[k]<=0:
                M[j,k]=1

    if j+1<N+4:
        x_A1B1 = array_x2[j]-array_x1[j]
        y_A1B1 = array_y2[j]-array_y1[j]
        x_A1A2 = array_x1[j+1:]-array_x1[j]
        y_A1A2 = array_y1[j+1:]-array_y1[j]     
        x_A2A1 = -1*x_A1A2
        y_A2A1 = -1*y_A1A2
        x_A2B2 = array_x2[j+1:]-array_x1[j+1:]
        y_A2B2 = array_y2[j+1:]-array_y1[j+1:]
        x_A1B2 = array_x2[j+1:]-array_x1[j]
        y_A1B2 = array_y2[j+1:]-array_y1[j]
        x_A2B1 = array_x2[j]-array_x1[j+1:]
        y_A2B1 = array_y2[j]-array_y1[j+1:]

        p1 = x_A1B1*y_A1A2 - y_A1B1*x_A1A2
        p2 = x_A1B1*y_A1B2 - y_A1B1*x_A1B2
        p3 = x_A2B2*y_A2B1 - y_A2B2*x_A2B1
        p4 = x_A2B2*y_A2A1 - y_A2B2*x_A2A1

        condicion_1=p1*p2
        condicion_2=p3*p4                         

        for k in xrange (N-j-1):
            if condicion_1[k]<=0 and condicion_2[k]<=0:
                M[j,k+j+1]=1
```

Here, the element Mij=1 if stick i intersect stick j and Mij=0 if not.

How can i optimize my algorithm? Graph theory is usefull in this case? How?

Waiting for your answers.

Thanks a lot!

Best regards

Comment: I doubt that graph theory can help here; where are you getting a graph out of this? What are the vertices? What are the edges? I'd think it more likely that this is a "computational geometry" problem.

Comment: The vertices would be the lines he draws, with edges connecting intersecting lines.  But with Monte Carlo, you generally find out the answer to whatever you want to know, and then start over.  1 simulation or 1 million simulations should use about the same amount of RAM (except for a few counters keeping track of your stats).